# Is there a way to pass a reference of "Globals.ThisAddIn" from a MS Word Add-In to a WinForms project in the same solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, office-interop, word-addins

I have a Windows Form App that needs to work with Microsoft Word documents and I am having trouble referencing "Globals.ThisAddIn" from the WinForms project in the same solution as the Word Add-In Project. When I try to access Globals.ThisAddIn, it throws an error that says, "Globals.ThisAddIn.get returned null."

The Code below is what throws the error. The "MyWord" class is a public class inside of the MS Word Add-In Project. It is being called from the WinForms Project in the same solution as the Word Add-In.

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Tools = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word;
public class MyWord
{

    public MyWord()
    {

    }


    public Tools.Document GetVstoDocument(Word.Document doc)
    {
        Tools.Document ToolDoc = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(doc);
        return ToolDoc;

    }

    public Word.Document OpenFromTemplate(string TemplatePath)
    {
        Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Add(TemplatePath);
        return doc;
    }
}
```

Currently, the Word Add-In Project is set to start at the same time as the WinForms App. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check ‘out of process clients’ and the clarification and instructions in this link [calling-code-in-vsto-add-ins-from-other-office-solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/calling-code-in-vsto-add-ins-from-other-office-solutions)